# Code::Blocks fails to debug with breakpoints

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

The debugger stops properly at my breakpoint, but when I press the "Next step" button on the toolbar, the debug cursor diappears, and Code::Blocks seems to lose connection with gdb (e.g. it's impossible to stop the debug). When I manually kill the gdb process, the IDE's Watches window shows this message for each variable:

```
<error reading variable ... (Cannot access memory at address ...)>
```

I've got Code::Blocks 16.01 on Ubuntu 16.04 with GCC 5.3.1.
My first thought was that gdb lacks debug data / optimization is used, but I've got `-g3 -ggdb` flags and no optimization enabled.

I've used C::B for long before, and the problem may be rare or new (due to one of the updates). Also, some other functions can be debugged correctly.

**UPD.** Suprisingly, I've found out that it is impossible to debug just a number of lines at the beginning of the function:

```
bool Entangle::ProcessFile(size_t task_index)
{
    //Preparing name for temp file
    wxString name = u.tasks[task_index], error_text;
    wxFileName fname(name);
    wxString temp_path = RNG::TempName(fname.GetPathWithSep());
    ErrorTracker::SetFile(name);

    ullong fsize=0;

    //Creating the Entangle header
    Header head(fsize);

    /** Opening files **/
    //Opening original file
    BinFile In(name, ios_base::in);
```

The code below can be debugged normally.

Comment: well, if you REALLY messed up the stack, it can become undebugable.. not sure though.  Try running it with valgrind or if you have access to clang (such a better compiler), you can use sanitize=address http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html

Comment: No, there's nothing special in Valgrind's output.

Comment: More details found - see the question.